why firebase push notifications not working on iOS device , if working fine on android device
I have followed the exact steps listed here in this guide: https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-fcm-flutter#0 . I believe this may be an official guide provided by firebase themselves. The guide does work when attempting to send a notification to an Android device, but I'm not getting anything for an IOS device.
When attempting to use the server sample code provided (to send the notification) but to send a notification to an IOS simulator, i am initially getting:

com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Request
contains an invalid argument." Then on subsequent runs of the server
code i'll get
"com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingException: Requested
entity was not found.

Yes, I have added the p12 certificate  to firebase and  team id and I have tried with p8 certificate initially no use, that's why I had to use p12.  There seems to be little information I'm seeing online about this. I'm really trying to stay within flutter and not have to use swift/objective-c solutions unless i have to. If anyone could provide help regarding this, it would be great.
I have followed the provided guide closely, and though it does work for Android devices, I am not seeing it work for iOS.  I have tried manually adding the GoogleService_Info.plist but that seemed to break it. Seems it's already generated/added, since running the project after adding it will lead to a failed build.  I have also reviewed many of the other similar questions/answers but they are not working for me.
{
    "error": {
        "code": 404,
        "message": "Requested entity was not found.",
        "status": "NOT_FOUND",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.firebase.fcm.v1.FcmError",
                "errorCode": "UNREGISTERED"
            }
        ]
    }
}

If I use apple push notifications sending service in the apple developer account I'm receiving notifications even for the simulator also. but when trying with firebase service, not working what could be the issue?

install node, go to apple website create APN and upload .v8 file to firebase. then run "flutterfire configure"
